# Bird eye view of unknown data set

Tags: data-visualization, dataset, mean, histogram, barplot

Pardon me if this question does not fit this site (or SE engine in general) but I do not know where to post it. Suppose that you have unknown data set which you want to explore. What functions/methods/techniques should I use to get birds eye of the data? I guess it depends on the data. I'm particularly interests in the ordered integers (but feel free to post other types also). Few examples that comes to my mind are: histograms, barplots, (moving) mean (aka average) median mode variance standard-deviation. What else? Thank you.

Comment: It depends to a large extent on what you want to do with that data, more so than on characteristics of the data itself.

Comment: @MaartenBuis thanks for reply. I've expected such answer therefore I'm asking for birds view. Can you recommend e.g. some literature ?

Comment: This is a broad question: it would seem to require [entire books to answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22434). I dislike the duplicate thread (because the answers focus on graphical techniques rather than on EDA *per se*), but it looks like exactly the question you are asking.

Comment: @whuber hmm seems that the linked question is mainly dealing with problems related to visualization.