# Ansombe-quartet-like (pedagogical) examples to demonstrate power of visualizations

Tags: r, interactive-visualization, data-visualization

The Anscombe Quartet powerfully makes the point about the effectiveness of a visualization.

Do people have other (pedagogically tested) vignette/dataset examples, especially based on economic/business data, for which using the **right** visualization helps the analyst gain unique insights about patterns in the data?

Comment: Pretty much any example from any of [Edward Tufte](https://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/)'s books?

Comment: This is, indeed, a very broad question, but it nevertheless can be answered. Read: Cleveland, W. S. *The Elements of Graphing Data* and *The Visual Display of Quantitative Information* Wainer, H. *A Trout in the Milk*

Comment: Many thanks to the moderator and commentators.  I own all of Tufte and Cleveland books (as well as Tukey's EDA) and have been scanning through them for quite a while.

Comment: Regarding "How to Ask":  I did try to make intent clearer—pedagogically tested examples.  

**Search, and research:** not just the aforementioned books but other sites, etc.
**Be specific:** while I agree the Q is broad and open-ended, I submit that it is not vague.
**Make it relevant to others:**  should be relevant to teachers and even students

Comment: Also of possible interest: [Modern successor to Exploratory Data Analysis by Tukey?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/22434/)